# Testing ASync method with JUnit in Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring-async

I have a scenario where i need to test async method.
I have XML based configuration and is looks like below

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor"
        scheduler="myScheduler" />
    <task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5" />
    <task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10" />
```

Original Async method in controller as below

```
@Async
    public Future<ResponseEntity<?>> saveData(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        byte[] gzipContents = null;
        try {
            gzipContents = file.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        }
        if (gzipContents != null) {
            FileDTO fileDTO = new FileDTO(gzipContents);
            boolean response = storingService.processData(fileDTO);
            return new AsyncResult(new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiResponse<Boolean>(response, true), HttpStatus.OK));
        }
        return new AsyncResult(new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiResponse<Boolean>(false, true), HttpStatus.OK));

    }
```

And my test case looks as below.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class TestSave extends BaseIntegrationTest {

        @Test
        public void testTrackingDataSave() throws Exception {
            // setup
            MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc
                    .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload(API_TESTER_SAVETRACKINGDATA)
                            .file("file", readFileBytesFromClasspath("testdata/output_sample1.txt"))
                            .header("certificate", testerCertificate))
                    .andExpect(request().asyncStarted()).andReturn();

            this.mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult)).andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
                    .andExpect(status().is(200));
    }}
```

When u run this test i am getting exception as async started expected as true but false.

How do need to proceed to fix this problem. Am i missing something..?

Comment: Could be either you are getting 404 or 400 when doing your request, I had the same issue and to find out the problem debugged the returned value of `perform(...)`. Check the status code returned first and then debug the line to get the causing exception.

Comment: @swamybabun could you be able to solve this problem?

Comment: No,  I couldn't solve it.